# how to add custom category to display area with blog in joomla?

Tags: joomla

In joomla 3.2 I have created a new category with name struts2. But when I create articles under this category it's not getting displayed in the default page. Only if I select the category as blog then only it is displaying the content area. How to add mu category struts2 to the default category (blog) which is displaying by default?

Comment: On the blog when you click on the article does it open? It looks like a permission issue. The blog view is showing the intro text if configured.

Comment: I am able to view by search or typing the complete URL. The problem it doesn't showing by default if a make it under custom category instead of blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the categories menu, struts2, in the options tab under 'Alternative Layout'
 select 'Blog'. Then in the Home page menu item, in the Layout tab under Categories add struts2. It should work.

Comment: I done the first point u mentioned. I am unable to get the second point u said `Then in the Home page menu item, in the Layout tab under Categories add struts2. It should work.' Where it is?

Comment: I am using Joomla 3.1

Comment: I'm assuming that your home page is the default joomla 3 homepage. If you look under the "Home" menu name it should read "Articles » Featured Articles". So if you click to edit it and go to the "Layout" tab in the section "Select Categories" and click on the box, a dropdown will appear. Select the category struts2 from there.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to get you again. Can you please tell clearly. My version is 3.2.1. where is If you look under the "Home" menu name it should read "Articles » Featured Articles"`' ?

Comment: Menus>Main Menu>Add New Menu Item.  
In the Details Tab at "Menu Item Type" click "Select" in the popup that appears click Articles>Featured Articles.
In the Details Tab, on the right, click the "Yes" button under the "Default Page".
In the Layout Tab at "Select Categories" on the box "All Categories, Select some options" click and select the struts2 category from the dropdown that appears.
Name the menu and save it. In the new default page it should show the category.
If no articles are shown edit an article in the struts2 category and click the "Yes" button under "Featured" on the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it's working fine. But Is there a way instead of doing this directly without specifying the article as featured article. (Only by category)

Comment: Menus>Add New menu item.
Select>Articles>Category Blog
In "Choose a category" select struts2
On the right click "Yes" under "default page" to set this as home page.
It will show that category items.

Comment: Thanks, But It allows to select only one category type. I want to select more than one. For example struts2 and tomcat categories should come to the feed automatically.